# Turn nested hash into single hash

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash, nested

I want to turn this sample data:

```
{"2018-05-16"=>{
  "ABCD"=>{929119=>0.14174555, 338296=>0.13858019, 332058=>0.13680765, 449614=>0.13679536}}}
```

into this single array of hashes:

```
[
  {"target_date"=>"2018-05-16", "location"=>"ABCD", "id"=>929119, "value"=>0.14174555},
  {"target_date"=>"2018-05-16", "location"=>"ABCD", "id"=>338296, "value"=>0.13858019},
  {"target_date"=>"2018-05-16", "location"=>"ABCD", "id"=>332058, "value"=>0.13680765},
  {"target_date"=>"2018-05-16", "location"=>"ABCD", "id"=>449614, "value"=>0.13679536}
]
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: The question is implied and I imagine doesn’t  need to be explicit for the brilliant minds of this forum. If not, then how do I achieve the above?

Comment: What sawa means is: "What is the specific problem with the code you have written trying to solve this problem". As it stands now, it looks like you want us to write your code for you, so it would be best if you included the code you have written, the error message you are getting, and also explain the rules how to convert the input into the output instead of just giving a single example.

Comment: Understood. I have since solved this issue. Thanks to all for your assistance, code or otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
h = { "2018-05-16"=>{
        "ABCD"=>{
          929119=>0.14174555,
          338296=>0.13858019,
          332058=>0.13680765,
          449614=>0.13679536
        }
      }
    }

dat, v = h.first
  #=> ["2018-05-16", {"ABCD"=>{929119=>0.14174555, 338296=>0.13858019,
                               332058=>0.13680765, 449614=>0.13679536}}]
loc, f = v.first
  #=> ["ABCD", {929119=>0.14174555, 338296=>0.13858019, 332058=>0.13680765,
  #             449614=>0.13679536}]
g = {"target_date"=>dat, "location"=>loc }
  #=> {"target_date"=>"2018-05-16", "location"=>"ABCD"}
f.map { |k,v| g.merge("id"=>k, "value"=>v) }
  #=> [{"target_date"=>"2018-05-16", "location"=>"ABCD", "id"=>929119,
  #     "value"=>0.14174555},
  #    {"target_date"=>"2018-05-16", "location"=>"ABCD", "id"=>338296,
  #     "value"=>0.13858019},
  #    {"target_date"=>"2018-05-16", "location"=>"ABCD", "id"=>332058,
  #     "value"=>0.13680765},
  #    {"target_date"=>"2018-05-16", "location"=>"ABCD", "id"=>449614,
  #     "value"=>0.13679536}]
```

Another way--which can be generalized--follows.

```
h.each_with_object([]) do |(k0,v0),arr|
  v0.each do |k1,v1|
    v1.each.map do |k2,v2| 
      arr << { "target_date"=>k0, "location"=>k1, "id"=>k2, "value"=>v2 }
    end
  end
end
  #=> <same as for first method>
```

Note that this works with hashes having multiple dates and/or locations, such as the following.

```
{ "2018-05-16"=>{ "ABCD"=>{ 92=>0.14, 44=>0.13 }, "EFGH"=>{ 12=>0.24, 34=>0.23 } },
  "2018-05-17"=>{ "ABCD"=>{ 52=>0.34, 34=>0.33 }, "EFGH"=>{ 42=>0.44, 74=>0.43 } } }
```

For this hash the following array would be returned.

```
[{"target_date"=>"2018-05-16", "location"=>"ABCD", "id"=>92, "value"=>0.14},
 {"target_date"=>"2018-05-16", "location"=>"ABCD", "id"=>44, "value"=>0.13},
 {"target_date"=>"2018-05-16", "location"=>"EFGH", "id"=>12, "value"=>0.24},
 {"target_date"=>"2018-05-16", "location"=>"EFGH", "id"=>34, "value"=>0.23},
 {"target_date"=>"2018-05-17", "location"=>"ABCD", "id"=>52, "value"=>0.34},
 {"target_date"=>"2018-05-17", "location"=>"ABCD", "id"=>34, "value"=>0.33},
 {"target_date"=>"2018-05-17", "location"=>"EFGH", "id"=>42, "value"=>0.44},
 {"target_date"=>"2018-05-17", "location"=>"EFGH", "id"=>74, "value"=>0.43}]
```